# Giving the Big O, Big Theta and Big Omega for a function

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

How can one give Big O, Big Theta or Big Omega for a function like

```
T(n) = n + 10*log n
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get the complexity for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all lower-order terms and constants and you get:

```
Θ(T(n)) = Θ(n + 10*log(n)) = Θ(n)
```

Since this is a tight bound (`Θ`) we also infer upper and lower bounds as `O(n)` and `Ω(n)`.